How can I find the length of the longest common substring between two strings efficiently?
I have two strings, s1 and s2, and I need to find the length of the longest substring that appears in both strings. The substring must be contiguous in both s1 and s2.
For example:

If s1 = "abcde" and s2 = "cdefg", the longest common substring is "cde", which has a length of 3.

If s1 = "abcdef" and s2 = "ghijkl", there is no common substring, so the result should be 0.


I'm looking for an efficient solution that can handle large strings, up to 1000 characters long.
I tried using a brute force method by checking all substrings of one string and seeing if they exist in the other string. However, this approach is too slow for large input sizes. I was expecting an efficient solution using dynamic programming, but I'm not sure how to set it up correctly.
Here's what I've tried so far:
def longestCommonSubstring(s1, s2):
    dp = [[0] * (len(s2) + 1) for _ in range(len(s1) + 1)]
    max_len = 0
    for i in range(1, len(s1) + 1):
        for j in range(1, len(s2) + 1):
            if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1] + 1
                max_len = max(max_len, dp[i][j])
    return max_len

This works fine for smaller test cases, but I'm wondering if it's the most efficient solution or if there are better approaches. Is there a way to improve it, or is this a reasonable approach for large inputs?


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring

When asking a question about code, the very first tag you should add is for the language that you're using. Doing so not only helps get it in front of the people most likely to be able to answer, but helps future users find it when searching. Please [edit] to add that tag.

i was add comment thank you

Did you see the Wikipedia link? It should have all the info you need. If not, please improve your question to mention why that wouldn't work for you.

When visiting the en.wikipedia page, don't miss the talk paragraph about the DP procedure presented.
